# Mailchimp API invalid server

Tags: python, mailchimp

I'm trying to connect to the Mailchimp API but keep getting the following error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='invalid-server.api.mailchimp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /3.0/lists (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcc6c043760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

According to the error message, I may be passing an invalid server, however, when I check my Mailchimp account I can see at my url that my server is `us2`, which is exactly what I have in my code (if I print my url I get `'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/'` )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fragment of code that I use to connect to my Mailchimp account. I have mangled my API Key for the sake of privacy.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    h = {'Authorization': 'Basic 6a18233428fdae72543ee2f64b26-us5'}
    r = session.get('https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists', headers=h)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(r.json())
```